# To change the property for part of a cell value on Excel by Python

Tags: python-3.x

Is it possible to change the property for part of a cell value (like: set "Demo" only to Bold letters of a cell value "Demo Data") on Excel by Python? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are looking to make part of a cell bold while other part remains normal, you can use xlsxwriter. Here is an example below...
Note that there are many other changes like color, etc. Refer to documentation [here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_rich_strings.html).

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Sample.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
#worksheet.set_column('A:A', 9)
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
segments = [bold, 'Demo ', ' data']
worksheet.write_rich_string('A1', *segments)
workbook.close()
```

Comment: I wonder whether openpyxl can achieve the same result as xlsxwriter at this point, anybody knows? thanks.

Comment: @star128 - Check this [link](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_rich_strings.html). You can do more things with xlsxwriter than openpyxl. However, the catch is that you will need to create a file in xlsxwriter. In case you have an existing xlsx file and want to edit it and make changes, xlsxwriter cannot do that, but openpyxl can. So, it is more a case of what your requirement is

Answer (score 0):

```py
from openpyxl.styles import Font
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
a1 = ws['A1']
a1.value = 'Demo Data'  # set value
ft = Font(bold=True)   # set bold 
a1.font = ft  # apply
wb.save('font.xlsx')  # save
```

Comment: Just want to change the property for part of a cell value, like: set "Demo" only to Bold letters of a cell value "Demo Data", not the whole cell, other part remains normal.